# Android: why ImageView.getWidth() doesn't correspond to image resource width?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I have a 'image950.png' square image in my bundle with a size of 950x950 pixels (smaller than my screen width).

When I set it like this:

```
 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/myImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="#FFFF00"
                android:src="@drawable/image950"
                />
```

When I check the size of myImageView:

```
 int w = floorImageView.getWidth(); // returns 831 and not 950...
 int w1 = floorImageView.getMeasuredWidth(); // returns 831 and not 950...
```

I get 831 px instead of 950. (nota: I run a Samsung S20+)

Why do I get this result and how to get the expected result?

Thanks !

Comment: that is the width the actual view has, not the width of the image, I'm not close to my pc but you can try getting the actual drawable I think context.resources.getDrawable(id).intrinsicWidth ??? something along those lines

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why the width of the actual view is smaller that the width of the image (=resource) if there is enough space to draw it ?

Comment: Please explore ScaleType Property in ImageView. It may help you lot.

Comment: Thanks. I tried all ScaleType options, I always get the same wrong value. :(

Comment: maybe you have padding on the view's parents, maybe you have a theme that enforces the minimum padding or margin, add the whole layout you are using and maybe we  could see something, also check the parent view, does its getWidth() also return 831? if so then it is constrained in some way by the parent

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Bitmap to get size of image:

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
        R.drawable.YOURIMAGE);


 Bitmap bitmap = bitmapOrg;
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);   
 byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray(); 
 long lengthbmp = imageInByte.length;
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I want. I want to know the width of the imageView once drawn. As far as I understand it should match the size of the bitmap in my case ; it is not the case, I don't understand why...

Comment: Then the problem is that using scaleType, you will change the size value of your image..